# Implement Circular Buffer for v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2

I'm looking for an efficient way to implement a circular buffer like object to continuously record from an webcam but only holding a fixed amount of time.  ie continuous monitoring of video stream but only keeping the last 2 secs in memory at any one time.

Answer (score 2):

`ffplay` executable has some queue implementation you can use it, check `ffplay.c`.

You'll import this structure `PacketQueue` and these functions:

```
static int  packet_queue_put_private (PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt)
static int  packet_queue_put (PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt)
static int  packet_queue_put_nullpacket (PacketQueue *q, int stream_index)
static int  packet_queue_init (PacketQueue *q)
static void packet_queue_flush (PacketQueue *q)
static void packet_queue_destroy (PacketQueue *q)
static void packet_queue_abort (PacketQueue *q)
static void packet_queue_start (PacketQueue *q)
static int  packet_queue_get (PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt, int block, int *serial)
```

And this implementation is pretty fast. `PacketQueue.nb_packets` will give you the number of video frames currently in the queue. 2 seconds worth of frames means `VideoFps * 2`, i.e. 60fps video, `nb_packets` maximum should be 120 frames. If try to implement this, you can easily add `packet_queue_discardpkt` to delete excess frames (oldest one) if it's > 2secs (i.e. 120 frames). I can give you an example on this `packet_queue_discardpkt` function.
Hope that helps.

Comment: This looks really promising.  Thank you for the response.  My C is pretty weak so I definetely would appreciate any help you're willing to provide.  Ultimate goal of this would be to implement an instant replay setup for our Cub Scout Packs Pinewood Derby.